# How do I sort in Excel 2007 but do not go to the top of the list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

How do I sort in Excel 2007 but do not go to the top of the list?  I have a filtered set of data many rows long.  However, when I am deep in the list, and select to change the sort by method on one of the columns, my active cell is moved all the way back up to the top of the list.  This seemed to change with Excel 2007 over previous versions.

Comment: Your active cell shouldn't move, it should stay at the absolute location it was at before, but it won't move with what you had selected. You don't want your view to change back up to the top?

Comment: No.  I'm wanting my view to stay down where I was in the list.  I can't figure out why the view changes, but the active cell stays where it was.  Seems silly.  Seems like the view would stay on the active cell.

Comment: Unfortunately, this cannot be changed

Answer (score 0):

When you sort in Excel 2007 the window jumps up to show the top of your list, but the active cell is still on the same row it was before you sorted. To move the visible window back to the active cell, use the arrow keys.

- To stay on the same row, press `Left` or `Right`.
- To stay on the same column, press `Up` or `Down`.

I generally press `Left` & `Right` or `Up` & `Down` so that I've returned to the exact same cell that was active prior to the sort.